# How to read a file content from EF Configuration.cs file?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF 6 Code-base migration. 
I want to read the file from Configuration.cs Seed() method to insert as default data.
I am using HostingEnvironment.MapPath() as below:

```
string _homeContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Data/DefaultContents/Home.html"));
```

But HostingEnvironment.MapPath return null value when I run the **Update-database** command from **Package-Management Console**.

> Running Seed method.
>
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: path
>      at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)

**Kindly advise how to read the physical file from Configuration.cs Seed() method.**

Answer (score 2):

May I answer by myself.

Server.MapPath and HostingEnvironment.MapPath is not available in this time because HttpContext object is not ready yet.

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory return "..\your project directory\bin"

E.g. C:\YourSolutionDirectory\YourProjectDirectory\bin

But we need to go up from "**bin**" folder, so that using **Path.Combine()** method and get exact file path.

```
string homeFile = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..", @"Data\DefaultContents\Home.html");
```

> Result: C:\YourSolutionDirectory\YourProjectDirectory\Data\DefaultContents\Home.html